# CORS - Paw and cURL work, but not jQUery code

Tags: jquery, paw-app

Accessing the Wikipedia API works in Paw, as does the cURL code Paw generates.  The Paw jQuery code fails, however, generating a CORS error.

```
// My API (POST https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php)

jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?" + jQuery.param({
        "action": "query",
        "list": "search",
        "srsearch": "Feynman",
        "format": "json",
        "srlimit": "10",
    }),
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({

    })
})
.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log("HTTP Request Succeeded: " + jqXHR.status);
    console.log(data);
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("HTTP Request Failed");
})
.always(function() {
    /* ... */
});
```

Adding `dataType: "jsonp",` before `type: "POST"` seems to work. Is it reasonable for Paw to recognize the problem and add whatever code is appropriate?  My main motivation in purchasing Paw was the hope that if the API call worked in Paw, the jQuery code would work as well.  Thanks!

Comment: Sincere apologizes for the super late follow up. This isn't an issue with Paw or the jQuery code you have, it's because web browsers enforce CORS when requests are to an external host. You made a JSON request with Paw and it worked, so generated jQuery is JSON too. See Wikimedia API about JSON & CORS: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Cross-site_requests